# Set distinct DataSource to DAOs depending on package name

Tags: java, spring, datasource, dao, spring-transactions

I'm using simple JDBCTemplate in my Spring app.

I have multiple DataSources that I want to apply to my DAO classes depending on the package name.

What I'm doing now is the following:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/a.jdbc" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.pui.PuiJdbcTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/a.jdbc2" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.pui.PuiJdbcTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>
```

I define two dataSources and two transactionManagers, and then I set in each DAO the dataSource:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource2")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

It works, but I want to know if there exists a better way to set it, mainly because of the transactions, because they are always being created over the "dataSource" bean, never over the "dataSource2" one.

Maybe one solution is to override the TransactionInterceptor class from Spring, and bring a customised solution to obtain the correct TransactionManager...

Comment: You need separate `TransactionManager` and `JDBCTemplate` for each `Datasource`. You may, of course, create JDBCTemplate in your context (XML) and inject it to DAO. And second, `@Transactional` has property `transactionManager` to select certain TM for transaction - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#transactionManager--

Comment: Yes Eugene, I know all of that. But I want to know if there is a better way to set automatically the JdbcTemplate to the DAOs in the XML, depending on the name of the package. Nevertheless, even if I do your solution, when Spring tries to get the PlatformTransactionManager, always returns the default one (the one with "transacitonManager" name). That's because the <pre>@Transactional</pre> annotations are defined in the DAO superclasses (that belong to a Framework), and I want to "override" these <pre>@Transactional</pre> in the concrete subclasses.